# R compare two dataframes by row, only reporting the discrepancies once

Tags: r, dataframe, compare, summary

so I want to compare two data frames with regard to the characteristics of one column, or more precisely, I want to compare the Country-Names in the two dataframes in order to find differently spelled Country names. I wrote the function

```
summary(comparedf(data.frame1, data.frame2, by = "CountryName"))
```

to then match the Country Names and write functions to change them in the second data frame accordingly. However both data frames are pretty big and the country names are repeated over and over as it´s a panel data situation.
Does someone know how I can get R to only report the diverging country names once if they have no matches in the other dataset and not over and over for each row dedicated to this country?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Would an `anti_join()` work here?

Comment: try creating list of unique `countryname` for both dataframe and compare them using `for loop`.

Comment: You could try `dplyr::setdiff(df1$CountryName, df2$CountryName)`